# Triggering global events on jQuery 1.9

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <p>hello world</p>
</div>

<p id="message">Event not yet triggered</p>
```

And the following JS:

```
$('#foo').bind('customEvent', function() {
    $('#message').text('Event triggered!');
});

$.event.trigger('customEvent');
```

My `p` tag is changed in jQuery 1.8 ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaA2G/)), but not in 1.9 ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaA2G/1/)).

Why is this? I can't see anything relevant in the [changelog for 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/). What's the best approach to use in 1.9+?

Comment: Should be `$('#foo').trigger('customEvent');` as thats the element you bound the event to

Comment: +1 to what @adeneo said, and also ... you're on jQuery 1.9, you should be using `.on()` instead of `.bind()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a global style event you can trigger events on the document body. Triggering events on more specific elements can be more efficient but this may not be what you want.

```
$(document.body).trigger('customEvent');
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/7c8M7/

An alternative approach is to use a dedicated pub-sub library like: https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS